# How to adjust the size of a GtkGrid cell?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3, pygobject

I'm programming a little application in **Python** + **Gtk3**. I'm using a `GtkGrid` with one column and two rows.

In the first row I put: a `GtkScrolledWindow`, and inside it a `TreeView` with two columns.

In the second row I put: a `ButtonBox`, and inside it a `GtkButton`, a `ComboBox` and another `GtkButton`.

**Question is:** the second row (the bottom one with the buttons) has too much space above and below the buttons, so how can I do to set the height of that cell to match the height of the buttons, without "wasting" space above and below?

The code is [<s>here</s>](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10411539/Set-Wall-Gnome3.py) and this is a screen-shot of my program:

[image]

---

Update Note : This code added to question from [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141220132959/https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10411539/Set-Wall-Gnome3.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
# untitled.py                                                           #
#                                                                       #
# Copyright (C) 2013 Germán A. Racca - <gracca[AT]gmail[DOT]com>        #
#                                                                       #
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify  #
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  #
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or     #
# (at your option) any later version.                                   #
#                                                                       #
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,       #
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of        #
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the          #
# GNU General Public License for more details.                          #
#                                                                       #
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License     #
# along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#


import os
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

class SetWallGnome3(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the window"""
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Set Wallpaper in Gnome 3')
        self.set_default_size(400, 500)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # definimos los directorios
        home_path = os.environ.get('HOME')
        pics_dir = os.path.join('Pictures', 'walls')
        pics_path = os.path.join(home_path, pics_dir)

        # creamos las siguientes listas:
        # pics_list -> camino completo de las imágenes
        # pics_name -> nombre de las imágenes
        pics_list = []
        pics_name = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pics_path):
            for fn in files:
                pics_name.append(fn)
                f = os.path.join(root, fn)
                pics_list.append(f)

        # creamos una grilla
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid(column_homogeneous=True, row_homogeneous=True,
                             column_spacing=10, row_spacing=10)
        self.add(self.grid)

        # creamos una ventana con barras de scroll
        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER,
                                       Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

        # creamos la ListStore
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf, str)
        for name, pic in zip(pics_name, pics_list):
            pxbf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(pic, 100, 100, True)
            self.liststore.append([pxbf, name])

        # creamos el TreeView
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        # creamos las columnas del TreeView
        renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        column_pixbuf = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Picture', renderer_pixbuf, pixbuf=0)
        column_pixbuf.set_alignment(0.5)
        self.treeview.append_column(column_pixbuf)

        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText(weight=600)
        renderer_text.set_fixed_size(200, -1)
        column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', renderer_text, text=1)
        column_text.set_sort_column_id(1)
        column_text.set_alignment(0.5)
        self.treeview.append_column(column_text)

        self.scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport(self.treeview)
        self.grid.attach(self.scrolledwindow, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        # creamos el ComboBox para las opciones del wallpaper
        self.option_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
        opts_list = ['centered', 'scaled', 'spanned', 'stretched', 'wallpaper',
                     'zoom']
        opts_name = ['Centered', 'Scaled', 'Spanned', 'Stretched', 'Wallpaper',
                     'Zoom']
        for opts, names in zip(opts_list, opts_name):
            self.option_store.append([opts, names])
        
        self.option_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(self.option_store)
        self.option_combo.connect('changed', self.on_option_combo_changed)
        renderer_combo_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.option_combo.pack_start(renderer_combo_text, True)
        self.option_combo.add_attribute(renderer_combo_text, 'text', 1)
        self.option_combo.set_active(0)

        # creamos los botones
        self.buttonbox = Gtk.ButtonBox(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        self.buttonbox.set_layout(Gtk.ButtonBoxStyle.EDGE)

        self.button_about = Gtk.Button(stock=Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
        self.buttonbox.add(self.button_about)

        self.buttonbox.add(self.option_combo)

        self.button_apply = Gtk.Button(stock=Gtk.STOCK_APPLY)
        self.buttonbox.add(self.button_apply)

        self.grid.attach_next_to(self.buttonbox, self.scrolledwindow,
                                 Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)

    # callback para el ComboBox
    def on_option_combo_changed(self, combo):
        treeiter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if treeiter != None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            option, name = model[treeiter][:]
            print "Selected: option=%s, name=%s" % (option, name)

def main():
    """Show the window"""
    win = SetWallGnome3()
    win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Next time consider putting your code in the page so we can see it. That link 404's

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you're creating the GtkGrid with homogeneous spacing for columns and rows; this means that your columns and rows will receive the same size, which is the maximum natural size between all the columns and rows.

when creating the Grid, remove the `row_homogeneous=True` attribute. if you want the TreeView to expand, you should set the `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties to `True` on it, i.e.:

```
    # creamos una grilla
    self.grid = Gtk.Grid(column_homogeneous=True,
                         column_spacing=10,
                         row_spacing=10)

    [...]

    # creamos el TreeView
    self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)
    # set the TreeView to expand both horizontally and vertically
    self.treeview.set_hexpand(True)
    self.treeview.set_vexpand(True)
```

GtkGrid is a container and layout manager that respects the horizontal and vertical expansion and alignment flags on the GtkWidget, instead of having packing properties, like GtkBox or GtkTable.

Comment: Wow... it worked like a charm! Many thanks @ebassi for reading my code and for giving such an accurate answer.